# Upgraded to Debian 6.0.7 and server now does not boot

Tags: boot, debian-squeeze

Today, I upgraded my Debian Squeeze installation of my vps to 6.0.7. It included a kernel upgrade, but I left the kernel upgrade last, after upgrading all the other packages first. However, now the server cannot boot. After selecting the option from the grub menu, I get this:

```
Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-686 ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
[38504239.405909] Stuck ??
```

And that's it! The server is stuck there. This is a vps running on Xen virtualization. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote. Anyway, I removed the quiet parameter from grub and it seems that the boot process stucks at the `isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...` line.

Comment: I also reinstall the previous kernel. The vps provides a rescue system where I can boot, mount the disks and chroot.

Comment: Reinstall the new kernel. Check the kernel parameters and the Xen setup, perhaps the kernel is waiting forever for devices that won't show up (shouldn't happen, but...). Check Debian's bug reporting system for similar problems and workarounds.